# Ubuntu 16.4 can't boot, it runs into a blackscreen!

Tags: 16.04, boot, suspend, mac

I am fully aware there are some other similar questions were was asked here and there, but I can't find any solution for that. Or, it is possible I don't know how to solve it the way it was explained.

Info about my machine:
Macbook Air 2014 with 4GB RAM and i5. The main OS is Ubuntu 16.4 LTC with multiple kernels: 4.10.28 (default) and sometimes I use 4.10.42.

I always had some problems with the suspend mode as the laptop didn't respond well after a suspend. But, it's always worked to just hold the power button and restart to solve it.

Now, the computer turned off as I was late to plug it to power charger. I tried to turn it on. I decrypt the drive successfully, but then, I just have a blackscreen for hours no respond.

- I tried with the display light by pressing some keys, since I could be too low that I couldn't see anything.
- I tried with the recovery mode with all available kernels I had in front of me, it starts to do something, but then ends with:
  suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)

But, no further response!!

- I tried to do the "hibernate" solution suggested in some places, but I can't get to terminal.

  - I even tried to leave it starving on power to get it shutdown the same way it got to the suspend mode with the slightest hope, this could change anything, but negative!

I need the computer desperately! All my work is also suspended due to this bug.

So, it seems I can't wake it up from suspend mode.

Appreciate any help here. Thanks!

**After a while and reading comments in the web regarding my problem:**

NOTE: I will leave it here, in case anyone will need some help with such a problem in the future.

There are two diagnosis I came to:
1) a problem in some packages or in the new os updates I did recently without restarting afterwords. It happened with me once, but the drive was not encrypted and started after login in where I faced a black screen and then sometimes blue screen; however, the only difference was the lid was bright enough to see the cursor (I say this cuz with certain kernels I had always very low brightness while booting.)

Since I wasn't able to get to termainal, I couldn't upgrade/udpate the packages/system files if it was the problem.

2) the suspend problem, as no kernel (I had four then) succeeded with booting. No response when choosing recovery mode. It loads everytime some messages and then stops by recovery mode. A normal mode with any kernel led to the black screen.

**What I did?**
I used a live usb to re-/install ubuntu. Reinstalling wasn't possible as the ubuntu installer couldn't detect any operating system in the laptop. At least, I was able to pull out my data and back it up (classic backup: copy/paste).

I had also the possibility to reinstall grub and see, if the problem lays there, but I had no experience in doing anything at all of this sort, so I took the easy way for me at the moment.

Thanks anyways!

Comment: I would remove power and remove the battery, wait a few moments then insert battery and apply power. Does it now boot ? If not, press esc key at switch on to get to your grub boot menu ( might have to tap constantly on esc). Do you have a recovery mode you can try ? If not, then highlight your main boot OS and press e (to edit). Find the linux line and replace "quiet splash" with "text", and press f10 to boot with this new (one time) setting. Do you see all the boot messages ? Is there any clue as to the problem ? Have you tried using no_console_suspend ?

Comment: It's macbook air, I can't unbrick it. I suppose, the only equivalent for removing battery is to hold power button long enough. . . I tried what you suggested and nothing had unfortunately worked. Every booting ended with either a blackscreen or hanged up while displaying messages. I will edit the question and add a summary to what I did.

Comment: At the grub menu, press "e" to edit your boot settings.  Locate the line that begins "Linux", specifies your "vmlinuz" aka kernel, then finally specifies boot parameters i.e. "quiet splash $VT_handoff" etc. Remove the boot parameters, i.e. "quiet splash" etc, and add the parameter "nomodeset".  Does it now boot ? You can also try removing all boot parameters and adding only "text", to boot into text mode. Does this get you any further ?