# Ubuntu 16.04 on 2016 Macbook fails to boot after power failure, freezes at suspending console(s)

Tags: 16.04, suspend, hibernate, macbook

Issue is exactly like [Ubuntu 16.4 can't boot, it runs into a blackscreen!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/998775/ubuntu-16-4-cant-boot-it-runs-into-a-blackscreen) , however after searching all over the Internet, I haven't found a working solution.

I left the system on without power which seems to have forced it to go into suspend when it almost ran out of battery.  Since then I have been unable to boot the system.

Macbook Pro 2016 model running Ubuntu 16.04 kernel  4.13.0-37.

Things I have tried:

- Booting from all installed kernels
- Running fsck from a Live Cd
- Recovery option on all installed kernels, this shows the system freezing at suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
- Using the no_console_suspend option with various combinations of nomodeset and text
- Resetting the Macbook NVRAM with "Command (⌘), Option, P, and R"

Last few lines of the syslog file:

```
May  5 01:23:00 vik-MacBookPro kernel: [32798.078950] usb 1-1.3.1: New USB device found, idVendor=1c4f, idProduct=0002
May  5 01:23:00 vik-MacBookPro kernel: [32798.078952] usb 1-1.3.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
May  5 01:23:00 vik-MacBookPro kernel: [32798.078954] usb 1-1.3.1: Product: USB Keyboard
May  5 01:23:00 vik-MacBookPro kernel: [32798.078956] usb 1-1.3.1: Manufacturer: SIGMACHIP
May  5 01:23:00 vik-MacBookPro kernel: [32798.082158] input: SIGMACHIP USB Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3.1/1-1.3.1:1.0/0003:1C4F:0002.0226/input/input560
May  5 01:23:00 vik-MacBookPro kernel: [32798.142036] hid-generic 0003:1C4F:0002.0226: input,hidraw5: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [SIGMACHIP USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1.3.1/input0
May  5 01:23:00 vik-MacBookPro kernel: [32798.144273] input: SIGMACHIP USB Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3.1/1-1.3.1:1.1/0003:1C4F:0002.0227/input/input561
May  5 01:23:00 vik-MacBookPro kernel: [32798.202097] hid-generic 0003:1C4F:0002.0227: input,hidraw6: USB HID v1.10 Device [SIGMACHIP USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1.3.1/input1
May  5 01:23:00 vik-MacBookPro mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 79: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3.1"
May  5 01:23:00 vik-MacBookPro mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 79 was not an MTP device
May  5 01:25:42 vik-MacBookPro kernel: [32959.828041] usb 1-1.3.1: USB disconnect, device number 79
May  5 01:25:42 vik-MacBookPro acpid: input device has been disconnected, fd 19
May  5 01:25:42 vik-MacBookPro acpid: input device has been disconnected, fd 20
May  5 01:25:42 vik-MacBookPro kernel: [32960.060668] usb 1-1.3: reset full-speed USB device number 45 using xhci_hcd
May  5 01:25:43 vik-MacBookPro kernel: [32960.456541] usb 1-1.3.1: new low-speed USB device number 80 using xhci_hcd
May  5 01:25:43 vik-MacBookPro kernel: [32960.563118] usb 1-1.3.1: New USB device found, idVendor=1c4f, idProduct=0002
May  5 01:25:43 vik-MacBookPro kernel: [32960.563126] usb 1-1.3.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
May  5 01:25:43 vik-MacBookPro kernel: [32960.563130] usb 1-1.3.1: Product: USB Keyboard
May  5 01:25:43 vik-MacBookPro kernel: [32960.563134] usb 1-1.3.1: Manufacturer: SIGMACHIP
May  5 01:25:43 vik-MacBookPro kernel: [32960.567935] input: SIGMACHIP USB Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3.1/1-1.3.1:1.0/0003:1C4F:0002.0228/input/input562
May  5 01:25:43 vik-MacBookPro kernel: [32960.625411] hid-generic 0003:1C4F:0002.0228: input,hidraw5: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [SIGMACHIP USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1.3.1/input0
May  5 01:25:43 vik-MacBookPro kernel: [32960.628355] input: SIGMACHIP USB Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3.1/1-1.3.1:1.1/0003:1C4F:0002.0229/input/input563
May  5 01:25:43 vik-MacBookPro kernel: [32960.689112] hid-generic 0003:1C4F:0002.0229: input,hidraw6: USB HID v1.10 Device [SIGMACHIP USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1.3.1/input1
May  5 01:25:43 vik-MacBookPro mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 80: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3.1"
May  5 01:25:43 vik-MacBookPro mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 80 was not an MTP device
May  5 01:26:05 vik-MacBookPro wpa_supplicant[1118]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STARTED EAP authentication started
May  5 01:26:05 vik-MacBookPro wpa_supplicant[1118]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=0 method=25
May  5 01:26:05 vik-MacBookPro wpa_supplicant[1118]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-METHOD EAP vendor 0 method 25 (PEAP) selected
May  5 01:26:05 vik-MacBookPro wpa_supplicant[1118]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PEER-CERT depth=3 subject='/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root' hash=687fa451382278fff0c8b11f8d43d576671c6eb2bceab413fb83d965d06d2ff2
May  5 01:26:05 vik-MacBookPro wpa_supplicant[1118]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PEER-CERT depth=3 subject='/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root' hash=687fa451382278fff0c8b11f8d43d576671c6eb2bceab413fb83d965d06d2ff2
May  5 01:26:05 vik-MacBookPro wpa_supplicant[1118]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PEER-CERT depth=2 subject='/C=US/ST=New Jersey/L=Jersey City/O=The USERTRUST Network/CN=USERTrust RSA Certification Authority' hash=1a5174980a294a528a110726d5855650266c48d9883bea692b67b6d726da98c5
May  5 01:26:05 vik-MacBookPro wpa_supplicant[1118]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PEER-CERT depth=1 subject='/C=US/ST=MI/L=Ann Arbor/O=Internet2/OU=InCommon/CN=InCommon RSA Server CA' hash=0a05c462756390dd1f1d5dd82794c300f04be789dce76d7e312f790d68fd385a
May  5 01:26:05 vik-MacBookPro wpa_supplicant[1118]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PEER-CERT depth=0 subject='/C=US/postalCode=02115/ST=MA/L=Boston/street=360 Huntington Ave./O=Northeastern University/OU=Information Technology/CN=wireless.northeastern.edu' hash=e046f4278920a78db4985b7e1e587c76b4b853af9452cffa86d0bd3d01a1ddf5
May  5 01:26:05 vik-MacBookPro wpa_supplicant[1118]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PEER-ALT depth=0 DNS:wireless.northeastern.edu
May  5 01:26:05 vik-MacBookPro wpa_supplicant[1118]: EAP-MSCHAPV2: Authentication succeeded
May  5 01:26:05 vik-MacBookPro wpa_supplicant[1118]: EAP-TLV: TLV Result - Success - EAP-TLV/Phase2 Completed
May  5 01:26:05 vik-MacBookPro wpa_supplicant[1118]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-SUCCESS EAP authentication completed successfully
May  5 01:26:05 vik-MacBookPro wpa_supplicant[1118]: nl80211: Unexpected encryption algorithm 5
May  5 01:26:05 vik-MacBookPro NetworkManager[860]: <info>  [1525497965.6915] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: completed -> 4-way handshake
May  5 01:26:05 vik-MacBookPro wpa_supplicant[1118]: wlan0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with 70:3a:0e:88:87:62 [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
May  5 01:26:05 vik-MacBookPro NetworkManager[860]: <info>  [1525497965.7052] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
May  5 01:27:09 vik-MacBookPro kernel: [33046.612030] usb 1-1.3.1: USB disconnect, device number 80
May  5 01:27:09 vik-MacBookPro acpid: input device has been disconnected, fd 19
May  5 01:27:09 vik-MacBookPro acpid: input device has been disconnected, fd 20
May  5 01:27:09 vik-MacBookPro kernel: [33046.838060] usb 1-1.3: reset full-speed USB device number 45 using xhci_hcd
May  5 01:27:09 vik-MacBookPro kernel: [33046.857857] hub 1-1:1.0: hub_ext_port_status failed (err = -71)
May  5 01:27:09 vik-MacBookPro kernel: [33046.858007] usb 1-1-port3: cannot reset (err = -71)
May  5 01:27:10 vik-MacBookPro kernel: [33047.441664] usb 1-1.3.1: new low-speed USB device number 81 using xhci_hcd
May  5 01:27:10 vik-MacBookPro kernel: [33047.547670] usb 1-1.3.1: New USB device found, idVendor=1c4f, idProduct=0002
May  5 01:27:10 vik-MacBookPro kernel: [33047.547673] usb 1-1.3.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
May  5 01:27:10 vik-MacBookPro kernel: [33047.547675] usb 1-1.3.1: Product: USB Keyboard
May  5 01:27:10 vik-MacBookPro kernel: [33047.547677] usb 1-1.3.1: Manufacturer: SIGMACHIP
May  5 01:27:10 vik-MacBookPro kernel: [33047.551046] input: SIGMACHIP USB Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3.1/1-1.3.1:1.0/0003:1C4F:0002.022A/input/input564
May  5 01:27:10 vik-MacBookPro kernel: [33047.610546] hid-generic 0003:1C4F:0002.022A: input,hidraw5: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [SIGMACHIP USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1.3.1/input0
May  5 01:27:10 vik-MacBookPro kernel: [33047.613311] input: SIGMACHIP USB Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3.1/1-1.3.1:1.1/0003:1C4F:0002.022B/input/input565
May  5 01:27:10 vik-MacBookPro kernel: [33047.670596] hid-generic 0003:1C4F:0002.022B: input,hidraw6: USB HID v1.10 Device [SIGMACHIP USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1.3.1/input1
May  5 01:27:10 vik-MacBookPro mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 81: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3.1"
May  5 01:27:10 vik-MacBookPro mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 81 was not an MTP device
May  5 01:28:09 vik-MacBookPro NetworkManager[860]: <info>  [1525498089.5594] manager: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
May  5 01:28:09 vik-MacBookPro NetworkManager[860]: <info>  [1525498089.5595] manager: sleeping...
May  5 01:28:09 vik-MacBookPro NetworkManager[860]: <info>  [1525498089.5596] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
May  5 01:28:09 vik-MacBookPro NetworkManager[860]: <info>  [1525498089.5604] device (wlan0): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'sleeping') [100 110 37]
May  5 01:28:09 vik-MacBookPro org.gnome.zeitgeist.Engine[2845]: #033[31m[05:28:09.561826 WARNING]#033[0m sql.vala:350: remove_storage_medium: 5, database is locked
May  5 01:28:09 vik-MacBookPro org.gnome.zeitgeist.Engine[2845]: #033[31m[05:28:09.561857 WARNING]#033[0m ext-storage-monitor.vala:416: Could not remove storage medium: remove_storage_medium: 5, database is locked
May  5 01:28:09 vik-MacBookPro whoopsie[1119]: [01:28:09] offline
May  5 01:28:09 vik-MacBookPro NetworkManager[860]: <info>  [1525498089.5721] device (wlan0): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'sleeping') [110 30 37]
May  5 01:28:09 vik-MacBookPro avahi-daemon[807]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::e455:aa13:deee:5f8b on wlan0.
May  5 01:28:09 vik-MacBookPro avahi-daemon[807]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address fe80::e455:aa13:deee:5f8b.
May  5 01:28:09 vik-MacBookPro avahi-daemon[807]: Interface wlan0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
May  5 01:28:09 vik-MacBookPro gnome-session[3011]: (deja-dup-monitor:4264): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 77 was not found when attempting to remove it
May  5 01:28:09 vik-MacBookPro gnome-session[1298]: (deja-dup-monitor:3225): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 81 was not found when attempting to remove it
May  5 01:28:09 vik-MacBookPro NetworkManager[860]: <info>  [1525498089.5909] dhcp4 (wlan0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 6386
May  5 01:28:09 vik-MacBookPro NetworkManager[860]: <info>  [1525498089.5913] dhcp4 (wlan0): state changed bound -> done
May  5 01:28:09 vik-MacBookPro wpa_supplicant[1118]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=70:3a:0e:88:87:62 reason=3 locally_generated=1
May  5 01:28:09 vik-MacBookPro wpa_supplicant[1118]: p2p-dev-wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
May  5 01:28:09 vik-MacBookPro avahi-daemon[807]: Withdrawing address record for 10.110.237.209 on wlan0.
May  5 01:28:09 vik-MacBookPro avahi-daemon[807]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv4 with address 10.110.237.209.
May  5 01:28:09 vik-MacBookPro avahi-daemon[807]: Interface wlan0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
May  5 01:28:09 vik-MacBookPro NetworkManager[860]: <info>  [1525498089.6093] dns-mgr: Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
May  5 01:28:09 vik-MacBookPro dnsmasq[2078]: setting upstream servers from DBus
May  5 01:28:09 vik-MacBookPro kernel: [33107.040883] brcmfmac: brcmf_inetaddr_changed: fail to get arp ip table err:-23
May  5 01:28:09 vik-MacBookPro dbus[810]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'
May  5 01:28:09 vik-MacBookPro systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
May  5 01:28:09 vik-MacBookPro NetworkManager[860]: <warn>  [1525498089.6405] sup-iface[0x2024620,wlan0]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
May  5 01:28:09 vik-MacBookPro dbus[810]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
May  5 01:28:09 vik-MacBookPro systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
May  5 01:28:09 vik-MacBookPro NetworkManager[860]: <info>  [1525498089.6413] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
May  5 01:28:09 vik-MacBookPro nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [wlan0]: new request (2 scripts)
May  5 01:28:09 vik-MacBookPro nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [wlan0]: start running ordered scripts...
May  5 01:28:09 vik-MacBookPro NetworkManager[860]: <info>  [1525498089.6427] device (wlan0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping') [30 10 37]
May  5 01:28:10 vik-MacBookPro wpa_supplicant[1118]: nl80211: deinit ifname=p2p-dev-wlan0 disabled_11b_rates=0
May  5 01:28:10 vik-MacBookPro systemd[1]: Starting TLP suspend/resume...
May  5 01:28:10 vik-MacBookPro wpa_supplicant[1118]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlan0 disabled_11b_rates=0
May  5 01:28:10 vik-MacBookPro systemd[1]: Started TLP suspend/resume.
May  5 01:28:10 vik-MacBookPro systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
May  5 01:28:10 vik-MacBookPro systemd[1]: Starting Hybrid Suspend+Hibernate...
May  5 01:28:10 vik-MacBookPro systemd-sleep[3969]: Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: (nil)  error: No such file or directory
May  5 01:28:10 vik-MacBookPro kernel: [33108.073075] PM: Hibernation mode set to 'suspend'
May  5 01:28:10 vik-MacBookPro systemd-sleep[3970]: /lib/systemd/system-sleep/wpasupplicant failed with error code 255.
May  5 01:28:10 vik-MacBookPro systemd-sleep[3969]: Suspending system...
```

I believe that the system is somehow stuck thinking it needs to suspend.  If there was a way to override some lockfile, hibernation file or suspended session, I think it might solve the issue.

I am out of ideas for things to try, so please help with any suggestions / ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured out a workable solution and want to leave it here for anyone else (for me in the future) that might need it.  I remember having this issue a few months back and now I believe I was able to get around it by booting to one of the old kernels.  However, I had removed the old kernels so didn't have the option this time.
So after getting inspired from [Can't boot my MacBook Air 2017 after sudo pm-hibernate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1005400/cant-boot-my-macbook-air-2017-after-sudo-pm-hibernate?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) , I knew I needed an old kernel.  However this was tricky without being able to boot into the system.

A google search showed that I could do this relatively easily as described in [How to restore a system after accidentally removing all kernels?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28099/how-to-restore-a-system-after-accidentally-removing-all-kernels)  This way I installed kernel 4.8.0-53 and was sucessfully able to boot into it.  However, with this kernel my keyboard and mouse didn't work.  But after the successful boot, a forced power cycle allowed me to boot into my original 4.13.0-37 kernel.

Hope this helps others.